# Vit eModule Federation Host cannot build due to OOM

Tags: reactjs, vite, micro-frontend

I am turning a react 18 applciation form Webpack to vite, i can compile all the remote modules except the host one (`main`).
the problem is this one

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[16683:0x150008000]    23084 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 2043.4 (2081.4) -> 2043.4 (2082.2) MB, 1.79 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.465, current mu = 0.269) allocation failure; 
[16683:0x150008000]    24381 ms: Mark-Compact (reduce) 2044.2 (2082.2) -> 2044.2 (2082.7) MB, 1296.38 / 0.00 ms  (+ 1.6 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 1311 ms) (average mu = 0.298, current mu = 0

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
----- Native stack trace -----

 1: 0x100d1b5d4 node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0x100d1b7d4 node::ModifyCodeGenerationFromStrings(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0x100ebac64 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0x10109b6b8 v8::internal::Heap::stack() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0x1010998c8 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0x101090bb4 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0x101091450 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: 0x101075194 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: 0x1014433d8 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: 0x1017df954 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_ArgvOnStack_NoBuiltinExit [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: 0x1017858dc Builtins_ArrayPrototypePush [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: 0x107326db4 
13: 0x1071953f8 
14: 0x107196114 
15: 0x1071f816c 
16: 0x1071f55e0 
17: 0x1071899e4 
18: 0x10716b198 
19: 0x10709ebb8 
20: 0x1018452d8 Builtins_PromiseFulfillReactionJob [/usr/local/bin/node]
21: 0x10177a654 Builtins_RunMicrotasks [/usr/local/bin/node]
22: 0x101752794 Builtins_JSRunMicrotasksEntry [/usr/local/bin/node]
23: 0x100ffd280 v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::Invoke(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeParams const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
24: 0x100ffd730 v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithTryCatch(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeParams const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
25: 0x100ffd8dc v8::internal::Execution::TryRunMicrotasks(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::MicrotaskQueue*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
26: 0x1010254ec v8::internal::MicrotaskQueue::RunMicrotasks(v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
27: 0x101025c88 v8::internal::MicrotaskQueue::PerformCheckpoint(v8::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
28: 0x100c48c64 node::InternalCallbackScope::Close() [/usr/local/bin/node]
29: 0x100c4901c node::InternalMakeCallback(node::Environment*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*, node::async_context) [/usr/local/bin/node]
30: 0x100c60138 node::AsyncWrap::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
31: 0x100d21040 node::fs::FSReqCallback::Resolve(v8::Local<v8::Value>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
32: 0x100d2178c node::fs::AfterNoArgs(uv_fs_s*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
33: 0x100d16528 node::MakeLibuvRequestCallback<uv_fs_s, void (*)(uv_fs_s*)>::Wrapper(uv_fs_s*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
34: 0x10172ddf8 uv__work_done [/usr/local/bin/node]
35: 0x101731848 uv__async_io [/usr/local/bin/node]
36: 0x101743910 uv__io_poll [/usr/local/bin/node]
37: 0x101731e0c uv_run [/usr/local/bin/node]
38: 0x100c49754 node::SpinEventLoopInternal(node::Environment*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
39: 0x100d5b2e0 node::NodeMainInstance::Run(node::ExitCode*, node::Environment*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
40: 0x100d5b07c node::NodeMainInstance::Run() [/usr/local/bin/node]
41: 0x100ce56fc node::Start(int, char**) [/usr/local/bin/node]
42: 0x18c17d0e0 start [/usr/lib/dyld]
```

and here is my vite config resolved
https://pastebin.com/cXxiu4B2

I added more memory using the var NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=72768 but did not work

also updted my tscofig according to vite one and had no results.